# Intent_filter splash screen manifest Android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have a main class and a splash screen. the splash doesn't want to show and I'm fairly certain its the manifest.

Any thoughts?

```
    <application


    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
    <activity android:name="splash"></activity><activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Main" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intent filter applied to the activity called `.Main` makes it so the launcher will launch that as the Main activity in your application. To switch the focus you would have a manifest like the following:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
    <activity android:name="splash">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>        
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".Main" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Take a close look at the way the intent filters are set up now. the splash activity is set as `MAIN` and will be categorized as `LAUNCHER`

Comment: If I had a third class that I wanted to load before Main, how would I change it?

Comment: @TroothHertz what you specify with this intent filter is the activity it starts when you want to run your application, from your Splash activity you could throw an `Intent` to show the next screen and in that activity you can throw an `Intent` to go to `.Main`.

You need to take a look at the way Intents work though, it might be a confusing concept at first.